# Will beans or peas grow back after being topped by a deer?

Tags: pest-damage, beans, peas

A deer got at my peas and beans. The peas seem to still have some leaves and stem. The beans are missing most of their leaves. Do either plants have any chance of regrowing or should I scrap them all and replant?

Comment: A picture of the damage would making an estimate easier and more precise.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on how much plant material is left, but typically they will grow back.

I regularly pinch off the tops of my young pea plans and serve them in salads and the plants grow back just fine. With beans, it's usually the slugs that munch at them and they have more trouble or need to be replaced, but that's mostly because the slugs tend to eat the whole plants.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a few peas that would come back, I doubt any of the beans will make it.  Were they pole or bush beans?

I would plant more peas and beans.  They grow so fast that most people grow second and third crops before the end of the season.

As for the deer, depending on the size of your land, getting a few bales of old hay to put somewhere far away from your garden really helps. They've had a taste and won't forget so you need to erect some sort of fence.  They have black mesh deer fencing that is very cheap.  You could also get a water blaster on a motion sensor.

Comment: Big dog(s) is the only solution for deer.

Comment: @blacksmith37  You are right about that!  I've got 3 but they come in at night because we also have cougars and bobcat.  That is another reason we had to put up a huge greenhouse, deer/elk/rabbits galore.